# Allow limited resource questions in meta?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, resources, learning

Since resource based and general learning questions are a major point of discussion right now, what about having a handful of questions here in the meta that we can point people to in the FAQ along with when questions are answered on the main site? This might allow for a minor compromise where we have some beginner resources that we can point people to if they want to learn the language while at the same time, limiting the main site to fairly well defined question types that have a definitive answer.

Comment: I think the definitive answer to this problem will be to put the useful off-topic question in community wiki. Is there anyone who can enlighten me about how to do this?

Comment: @Ali - Moderators should have that ability.