# Where to ask about learning material

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language and Usage?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-and-usage)

[This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8/whats-the-best-utility-for-identifying-kanji) was closed as off topic because the site is supposed to discuss the actual language instead of auxiliary things like textbooks or learning tools.

If this is the case, **where** can I ask a question regarding this topic?

In my particular case, I would like to know which methods are the best for learning Kanji, especially what textbooks are considered the best (I have a lot of time commuting everyday, thus a is the most practical method for me). I assume other people may have questions like this one. Where can they be asked?

Thank you

Comment: Specifically [this answer](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/798/162) addresses the question.

Comment: As one additional note, there isn't one "best" method - what works for some people doesn't work as well for others.  And you might even change your studying approach partway through - several times!  People can tell you about their experiences and you may be able to glean something from that, in which case the chat room is probably the best place to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much!