# Pre-prepared messages

Tags: discussion

If you want to have pre-prepared messages that you expect to copy and paste as a comment multiple times, feel free to post them below. For example, a new user wanting to ask an off-topic question.

Comment: How do you intend it to be used? Redirect the user here, or copy and paste the message? Maybe you might want to elaborate the q and a section with these kind of texts.

Comment: @sawa I'm assuming it's intended to be similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments

Comment: I do not like long canned responses.  Comments should be short and to the point.  Otherwise, I am afraid that most people will ignore them.

Comment: Why are you doubling "pre"? Isn't one enough?

Comment: @sawa that's a good question that could be asked on English Language & Usage, but it's [cromulent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preprepare). My theory: English doesn't use "pared" *much*, so pre-prepared isn't exactly the equivalent of [o-mi-o-tsuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific_speech_in_Japanese#Rare_forms).

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Feel free to post your own version, or tweak mine. I think this question should be community wiki, come to think of it.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I will post mine if I feel the need for a canned response.  But usually I do not use a message with a fixed format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New user asks a question about learning techniques for [topic], or some other off-topic question**

Good on you for wanting to learn Japanese, and thanks for joining Japanese Language and Usage. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic, for reasons explained [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/798/91) [change link depending on what kind of off-topic it is]. There's a [post](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/756/91) on the meta site on resources for learning Japanese, and you are welcome to ask about [topic], and anything else within reason in the chat room, even though it's off-topic here. Feel free to ask other questions on the Japanese Language and Usage web site in the future. Ganbatte! (Don't give up!)