# Asking for free kana sound samples

Tags: discussion

Would it be alright to ask (on the main japanese.stackexchange.com site) if someone knows about (and could provide a link to) a free, downloadable (creative commons) kana audio set, I need it for a website that I'm working on (the website will be free to use and non-comercial, but I still need something that gives the permission for such use)? I am not sure if that falls into the scope of jpn se.

Comment: See: [Resources for learning Japanese](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese). And to save you some navigation: http://www.nhk.or.jp/lesson/english/syllabary/index.html

Comment: I personally think that questions like this _should_ be allowed, but the current consensus is that they are off-topic, as jkerian wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [resources page](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese), the best place to ask for things like this is the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language-and-usage).

We actually have a [policy against resource-related questions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/797/29) on the main site, but aside from the chatroom, don't have a really good way for people to ask about resources that aren't on the list.

As an imperfect solution, we've tended to move such requests over to meta, and typically answer them here.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, free sound samples of this sort are available on wikipedia. Although the english wikipedia set is incomplete, the japanese wikipedia offers a complete set.