# Close reasons are changing. Should we add custom "off-topic" close reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Close reasons are changing.  You can find more details on [meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/215040), but basically, this is what's happening:

- "too localized" is going away.
- "not constructive" and "not a real question" are being replaced by

  - "unclear what you're asking"
  - "too broad"
  - "primarily opinion-based"
- "off-topic" will let you pick a specific reason from a list OR let you type in why you think it's o/t.

As a community, we'll be able to add custom "off-topic" close reasons to the list, if we choose to do so.  Do we want to?  If so, **what reasons would we like to add?**

As a reminder, we already have [this meta question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/796/1478) about what questions are off-topic.  It might be a good place to start.

This won't be happening until sometime next week, so we have some time to talk about it first.

Comment: Gilles posted substantially the same question to meta.french.se, which might be interesting: http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/431

Comment: Why is "too localized" going away?  I thought that was a perfect choice when someone asks about song lyrics or something similar.

Comment: @istrasci Too many people were abusing it across the network to close questions they didn't want to answer.  You can see some of the discussion in the comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184164/160551).

Comment: I put together some stats, which may or may not be helpful here: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/closed-question-stats-june-2013

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't realize these reasons were changing across all SE.  I thought it was just our JL&U reasons.

Comment: Those interested in the network-wide "too localized" discussion and some examples of how "off-topic" is being expanded to cover some of TL can read the discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with the first suggestion over at meta.french.se, it would be a good idea for us to have a specific "translation request" close reason since those questions don't seem to fit under any of the other new categories - arguably the closest is "too broad" in many cases but that may be confusing for new users.

Some wording adapted from [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/29) could be used. It would probably help to have some upfront advice available on how to convert a "please translate this" question into a useful SE question, perhaps with examples, since there certainly are on-topic translation questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1047/1478), Troyen took a look at 14 questions closed as TL.  Of those 14, five were closed as typo questions.  Since we won't have TL anymore, it seems like our choices are:

- Leave the questions open.  This seems undesirable, because they're not useful to anyone.
- Close these questions as off-topic.  This is a little strange, because they seem like on-topic questions, for the most part.
- Close these questions with another reason:

  - Duplicate: We'd have to create a question to make them duplicates of.  I proposed something similar before, but in retrospect I think this is a bad idea.
  - Unclear what you're asking, too broad, primarily opinion-based: None of these reasons make sense to me.
- Delete these questions after a few days.  This is undesirable because, at times, we want to leave bad questions around even if they're closed, for example when another user adds useful information as a comment or answer.  We don't want to throw away the hard work of other users!

Although it seems a little odd to call typos "off-topic", perhaps we can do exactly that; in essence, we're declaring that the purpose of JLU is not to fixing your typos or misreadings.  Right now, I'm thinking that's our best choice.  **(This may change if a network-wide solution for typos is adopted.)**

So here's my attempt at writing up a close reason:

> **Typo**. This question was based on a typographical error or a misreading. Since the error has been corrected, there is no longer a question to be answered. if you feel there's still something you don't understand, please edit the question to include this information so it can be re-opened.

What do you think?

Comment: ssb also proposed an alternate phrase "no longer relevant"