# Closed question stats - June 2013

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Since we don't have that many questions, I decided to take a couple hours of my time and put together some stats on close reasons.

---

## Close reasons as of June 2013

```
 　
     close reason                  not deleted      deleted         total

     duplicate                     48               8               56 (1.8%)
     off topic                     17               8               25 (0.8%)
     not constructive              14               3               17 (0.6%)
     not a real question           56               28              84 (2.7%)
     too localized                 18               20              38 (1.2%)

     migrated (to meta)            0                18              18 (0.5%)
     migrated (to superuser)       0                2               2 (0.1%)
     migrated (to anime)           0                1               1 (0.0%)

     totals                        153              88              241 (7.8%)
```

<sup>The percents are out of all 3097 questions on the main site.  That number includes deleted questions.</sup>

---

## Samples of TL and OT usage to date

Since **too localized** is going away, and since custom **off-topic** reasons are intended to fill that gap, I thought it'd be nice to look at how we're currently using both close reasons.  So, I made some lists.  Since they're sorted numerically, items toward the end of the list are more recent.  *(Questions in `code` have been deleted, so if you have less than 2000 reputation, you won't be able to see them.)*

- The following questions were ***selected randomly***:

  - Closed as OT: [638](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/638) [1375](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1375) [2015](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2015) [`2384`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2384) [2852](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2852) [3405](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3405) [3795](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3795) [`4322`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4322) [`5478`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5478) [`5542`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5542) [`5815`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5815) [6174](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6174) [`6381`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6381) [`6539`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6539) [8311](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8311) [9616](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9616) [11034](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11034) [`11081`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11081) [12047](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12047) [12121](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12121)
  - Closed as TL: [2176](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2176) [`2942`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2942) [3700](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3700) [4557](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4557) [`4629`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4629) [`4734`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4734) [`4756`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4756) [`6048`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6048) [6212](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6212) [`6448`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6448) [`6882`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6882) [`6898`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6898) [9782](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9782) [11055](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11055) [11248](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11248) [`11609`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11609) [11920](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11920) [11922](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11922) [`12021`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12021) [12082](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12082)
- And the following questions are the twenty ***most recent***:

  - Closed as OT: [9655](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9655) [`9686`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9686) [11034](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11034) [11059](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11059) [`11081`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11081) [11086](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11086) [`11173`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11173) [11196](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11196) [`11220`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11220) [11344](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11344) [`11349`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11349) [`11439`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11439) [`11491`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11491) [`11494`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11494) [`11556`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11556) [11620](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11620) [12025](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12025) [12047](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12047) [12069](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12069) [12121](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12121)
  - Closed as TL: [`6448`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6448) [`6516`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6516) [6552](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6552) [`6882`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6882) [`6898`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6898) [9652](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9652) [9782](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9782) [11055](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11055) [`11118`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11118) [11248](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11248) [`11311`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11311) [`11372`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11372) [`11609`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11609) [`11610`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11610) [11695](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11695) [11920](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11920) [11922](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11922) [`12021`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12021) [12063](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12063) [12082](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12082)

As a reminder, we have a meta question for discussing custom close reasons [here](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/1478).

Comment: For those interested in the network-wide discussion about this change, look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns

Answer (score 2):

Since the ultimate point of this is to help see if the new close system will work adequately, I've gone through all the undeleted TL questions you listed to see if another close reason would suffice:

- [2176](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/what-is-a) - Apparently this was a typo and there is no specific close case to cover this.  Should they even be closed?
- [3700](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/is-the-pitch-data-correct-in-this-pdf-file-intended-for-learners) - Could have been left open if the document table was embedded in the question. Otherwise, maybe off-topic.
- [4557](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/verb-) - Should not have been closed.
- [6212](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6212/please-translate-this-question) - If it violates our translation guidelines, **off-topic: translation request**
- [6552](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/translation-doubts-) - Another typo question.
- [9652](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/how-to-write-aikido-wa-ichiban-budo-desu) - Why was this closed?
- [9782](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/meaning-of-) - Another typo question.
- [11055](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11055/cant-parse-) - Another typo question.
- [11240](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11248/) - **off-topic: translation request**
- [11695](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11695/why-you-dont-have-to-want-to-hold) - Another typo question.
- [11920](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/sore-ni-taru-and-rasen-ga-gotoku) - **off-topic: translation request**
- [11922](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-do-you-say-my-pride-will-not-let-me-fail-in-japanese) - **off-topic: translation request**
- [12063](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12063/japanese-to-english-need-help-with-a-sentence) - **off-topic: translation request**
- [12082](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12082/) - **unclear what you’re asking**

Overall, it seems like a translation sub-reason for "off-topic" would definitely be useful.  I'm not sure what to do about all the typo questions that used to fall under "too localized".  They aren't exactly "off-topic", just not very helpful to future visitors.  That's something which  is still being debated across the network.

Comment: I don't have 2K rep, so I can't review the deleted questions.

Comment: I voted to close on "9652 - Why was this closed?", because the question was to find the original source of a pseudo-Japanese sentence, which the OP had heard somewhere and claimed to be well-known. But we couldn't even find a source for the pseudo-Japanese sentence (in romaji), let alone the original "quote" in Japanese. Finding the original Japanese phrase of a romaji phrase, which doesn't exist, was then closed as "too localized", although it could have well been "not a real question".

Comment: Fair enough.  I probably would've voted to close prior to that final Update section on 12/5, which edited the question into an answerable question (and subsequently self-answered in the question itself). Now I think it's on-the-fence.