# Can we update the wording on a close reason?

Tags: feature-request, allowed-questions, faq-proposed

I voted to close [this topic](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12845/78) asking for proofreading and corrections.  I closed it as "Off-topic" with the following sub-choice:

> Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service. See: We don't do translations.

Here also is the link to the meta answer [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/799).

I think the wording in both of these places needs to be changed to include proofreading and corrections.  While it's debatable whether or not proofreading and corrections are *technically* classified as translations, the average user will probably see them as not the same, as I suspect the author of the above topic did.  So in their mind, they're probably thinking, "Cool, I'm not asking for a translation, so I'll post it", when really it is off-topic.

So the wording should be made clearer to indicated that we don't do any of the three "services".

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, we could add a separate close reason for proofreading.  Here's the wording used on the English Language Learners SE site, though we don't have to phrase it the same way:

> **Proofreading** questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.  See: *<link to meta question here>*

Each site-specific close reason has a link to the relevant meta discussion.  But do we *have* a meta question about whether or not proofreading is on-topic?  I think that we don't, because in the past these questions were closed as **too localized**.  And if we don't, we should make that question first so we have an explanation to link to.

---

### EDIT: I've started a discussion: [Should proofreading questions be allowed?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/should-proofreading-questions-be-allowed)