# Modifying Translation close reason to include Proofreading

Tags: discussion, status-completed, allowed-questions, scope, close-reasons

I'm reviving this meta post from two years ago - [Should proofreading questions be allowed?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1069/542)

The type of questions I'm looking at: 
[希代の剣豪の好敵手として祭り上げられた剣士を知る者など](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30224/542)
[Question about/with particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/)

It looks like we could close it under "too broad" since it's a bunch of things going on at once. But I think it's a proofreading question.

The last discussion was quite some time ago so I'm restarting it here on meta.

Let us know if you think :

- these kind of questions are of the proofreading type
- we should/should not have these kinds of questions
- we should just close them under "too broad"
- we should modify the translation close reason to include proofreading

Comment: What sort of wording would we use to cover translations and proofreading both in one reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the idea for including both in the same close reason is that we often get questions

> Help me translate this sentence
>   [English sentence]

which sometimes just get asked in a different way as

> Is this translation correct?
>   [English sentence poorly translated into Japanese]

We only have three custom close reasons (currently, "translation", "typo" and "resource/advice" questions) so we could amend the current translation close reason to read

> Questions asking for **translations**, **transcriptions** or **proofreading** are *off-topic* unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not to provide a bulk translation service nor to proofread your translations or transcriptions. See: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: I think by allowing the question through "prior research effort" would cause the problem to shift from "proofreading" to "too broad" since these questions typically ask several things at once.

Comment: @Flaw I don't understand what you mean. By "prior research effort" I'm envisioning a question clearly outlining what the OP has done to solve all his questions. If OP posts more than one question in the same post, it is usually very easy to edit out every but one question and ask him/her to post the other questions separately. In the case of a pure translation/transcription/proofreading question, editing out doesn't salvage the question, so no matter how many there are, we can close it with this close reason.