# "Proofreading" should be chosen as the close reason for "How does my hiragana look?" questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

From [What questions are not allowed on Japanese Language SE?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se), proofreading is [not allowed](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799). It's available as a close reason when closing questions:

> Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not to provide a bulk translation service nor to proofread your translations or transcriptions. [See: We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799).

When people ask "How does my handwriting look?" (example [1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30860/how-is-my-hiragana-hand-writing-and-which-one-needs-to-be-work-on) [2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30152/is-my-hiragana-good?rq=1)), proofreading either describes the close reason, or matches the spirit of it.

Note: Not everyone who has voted to close use the same close reason - we can't assume what an individual closevoter had chosen.

Having your question closed is unpleasant (I should know!), especially when you've put some effort in beforehand (in this case, it's the hand-writing and uploading the photo, not articulating the question itself). The least we can do is provide a close reason that accurately reflects what kind of question has been asked.

Comment: What's your suggestion?

Comment: @Earthliŋ that people use the "proofreading" close reason when closing such questions.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought you wanted that we explicitly mention handwriting in the close reason.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I've rearranged the title to make the message clearer.