# Is checking speech on topic or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Similarly to [this question](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1575/is-checking-handwriting-on-topic-or-off-topic), can I record myself talking in Japanese and ask people to comment on my pronunciation, accent and things like that?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1513/allow-audio-uploads

Comment: I think before we can really discuss this in detail, we have to figure out how to post audio files without the risk of losing them, even if the original posters become inactive. I've come across a couple of posts with dead audio links (of course after reading the question/answers to see if I found it interesting). This is very frustrating. Is soundcloud a guaranteed option like in [this Music.SE post](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23649/what-causes-this-weird-sitar-like-sound)?

Comment: It's like with images, nothing is guaranteed and everyone just uploads to imgur hoping that it won't die...

Comment: I think SE has a special agreement with imgur, and pictures uploaded via the interface get the URL **stack**.imgur.com and don't expire there.

Comment: Oh, that's good to know, I'll be using the interface from now on then.