# Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Japanese on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

> Would you please translate the following paragraphs into Japanese?
>
> - a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
> - All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
> - You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
> - There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
>     network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
> - Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!
> - Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it    be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more
>     interested people.
> - Please share the page and invite others to like it in order to have more committers and probably a successful launch
>
> I need them to post about [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry?referrer=8G2asYAyI_To9RoVf1VtPg2) in facebook pages that
>   are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
>   facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
>   more attention and so they might be seen by more people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, pure translation requests are off-topic, even for a single sentence.

However, if you are able to translate the sentence yourself and have trouble when researching a particular word, expression, or grammatical construction (etc.), you can give your translation and explain where you are having trouble. This type of question would be considered on-topic; in fact, questions like these form a large part of the questions on the site.

Please remember to give the question a descriptive title, **not** "Is this translation correct?", but something like "Can [Japanese word] be used to mean [English word]?" etc.

Comment: In fact I'm not learning Japanese but I had the same question in [meta french se](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/a/620/11584) and [meta german se](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1192/23750) and they advised me to ask it in the site's chat room. Am I allowed to do the same in Japanese chat room?

Comment: The chat room isn't intended as a bulk translation service either.

Comment: @sepideh If you need them translated professionally, hire a translator. It doesn't cost much money.

Comment: There are also semi-professional translators which will translate much better than Google Translate, but at a fraction of the price of a professional translator.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but no. You need to show your own research efforts and identify a specific concern in the text. Otherwise, your question will be closed. Japanese SE's [Help Center > Asking](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states:

> [Direct translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799) are off-topic. While we are very interested in
>   helping people who are having difficulty in their study of Japanese,
>   we are not willing to provide a translation service for cases where a
>   simple [dictionary](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/799#799) search combined with understanding the basics of
>   Japanese sentence construction would suffice.