# Can I ask to have my transcription of Japanese audio reviewed?

Tags: discussion

I wrote down the first minute of dialogue from the first episode of a Japanese cartoon/anime called "Chibi Maruko Chan", and would like to have my transcription reviewed to see if my Japanese listening skills were accurate to what was being said, am I allowed to ask for a review anywhere? Thanks. (Note the first episode is free on YouTube so all I'd have to do is link the video and copy + paste my transcription text)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can ask it.

Now seriously, this site is not appropriate for translations, transcriptions nor proofreading requests. I recommend you [Lang-8](https://lang-8.com/) for such purposes. You can find more options in [this answer](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/32952) as well.