# Spoken corpora resources

Tags: discussion, resources

Can you recommend any downloadable Japanese audio database? Preferably with a free license but commercial will do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://db.ciair.coe.nagoya-u.ac.jp/dbciair/speech_corpus.htm may help you.